# Render Animation Problems

Tags: animation

This is what I see when I'm in blender in the camera view:
[image]

but when I render the animation it comes out like this, I don't understand why
[image]

Comment: Does your camera object have any keyframes on it?

Comment: Yes there are key frames. Marked at 1 and 250.

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: thx , I shall tomorrow, I accidently erased that one, I'll redo it and if I don't get the result I want, I'll send it thanks

Comment: Looks like there's an object that is hidden from the view (eye icon in the outliner) but not hidden for rendering (camera icon, to be activated in the funnel shaped dropdown menu of the outliner).

Comment: thx, there was an object, a plane in "wire" view. I got it taken care of. Thx for all help